# How do I determine the correct Perforce client (workspace)?

Tags: perforce, perforce-client-spec

I have a Windows build bat that creates a Perforce commit and label on a successful build.

However, I have not found any way to *programmatically* determine the correct Perforce client.

Unlike all the other source control systems I'm aware of, p4 and p4v do not create any local config files specifying anything about the remote server.

While it is safe to set the Helix server address globally, and the user can be easily found, the client name is unique to each machine.

All of the methods I know of to specify the client require **manual** configuration:

1. "p4 set P4CLIENT=%my_client_name%"
2. "p4 -c %my_client_name%"
3. Create a ".p4config" file in every local workspace containing the client name and set P4CONFIG=.p4config

Note: Method (1) is global across all processes, so , and therefore breaks all other p4 commands that might be running on the same build or development machine.

We currently use method (3), however it relies on manually creating the proper .p4config file after setting up the workspace.

The Perforce server knows the local path of the workspace as I can see this in P4V, and p4 raises an error if the local path does not match the client specified in .p4config.

How can my batch file programmatically determine which p4 client matches the local machine, user and path?

Answer (score 2):

A few different things to think about that potentially eliminate this whole problem if you're able to take advantage of them:

- If you never set `P4CLIENT` in the first place, it defaults to the client host name, which will generally be unique to the client, and will automatically be availble to any `p4` command without you having to discover it.  (This applies more to `p4` users than P4V users, since P4V prompts you to type in a client name, IIRC, rather than simply using the host.)
- Local servers set up with `p4 init` will automatically set up a `P4CONFIG` for you in the workspace root.
- **If you're using P4V, and you set up your build script as a P4V custom tool, it will automatically set up the environment for you (including `P4CLIENT`) according to the active connection.**  (I'm bolding this one because my guess is that P4V users account for most of the difficulty you're having with this tool -- anyone using `p4` as their primary client has probably already figured out how to set up their environment in a way that works well with scripts.)

If none of those options are available, you can potentially write a script that tries to guess the right workspace based on available pieces of information:

- The current host (`P4HOST`) vs the `Host:` in the client spec
- The current directory (`PWD`) vs the `Root:` in the client spec
- The current user (`P4USER`) vs the `Owner:` in the client spec

For P4V users, examining the P4V config file is also an option.

Be aware, however, that a user who's gone out of their way to configure things in a confusing way can easily thwart any sort of automation you think of:

- A client spec can have a blank `Host:`, allowing it to be used from any host (this is generally bad, but you're allowed to do it)
- A client spec can have a `Root:` of `null` or `/` so that the mapping can span multiple drives (best avoided IMO, but occasionally useful)
- Multiple client specs can have the same or overlapping `Root:`s (a really bad idea IMO, but you're allowed to do it)
- You can use a client spec that's owned by someone else as long as it's not `locked` (I don't recommend this either, but it certainly happens)

How much you have to worry about users thwarting your efforts to guess their intentions is very site-specific.  Ultimately, my recommendation is to focus on making sure that clients are configured correctly, and that your tooling is able to take advantage of that configuration, rather than trying to come up with ways to guess how to fix the configuration within your tooling.

Comment: Sidebar: a lot of hassle would be avoided IMO if P4V just auto-created config files that other tools could use.  I've lobbied for this in the past, without success.  :)

Comment: You've not answered the question:

HOW do I determine which workspaces on the server are potential candidates?
A script only knows the following information:

- Helix Server URI, so it can talk to the server
- Local Hostname
- Local Username
- Local path to one file inside the desired workspace

Given that information, how does the script find the set of workspaces that the server thinks could be correct?

P4V clearly does do most of this, yet p4 does none of it.

Comment: And yes, the problem is entirely because Helix are fools. I'm only expecting to suffer this for another one to two years before we cancel our subscription.

Comment: p4 clients -u %username% gets partway there, however I have not found any way to filter by either hostname or local path. While I could just loop over all the workspaces for the user and get their details individually, this would hit the server very hard so does not scale.

Comment: `p4 clients -u` is in fact the trick.  Use `-Ztag` to get all the info in one shot.  Using a real scripting API (P4Python, P4Perl, etc) makes it much easier!

Comment: One possible approach could be giving everyone a P4V custom tool that sets up the config file (this is very very easy to script, even without using the client API, since P4V gives you all the needed inputs as custom tool args), and then having your tool error if there's no config file (and tell the user to go run the custom tool).